# RestTemplate GET request with request param

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, resttemplate

I use RestTemplate for GET Request with requestParam as :

```
final String Url = "http://localhost:8080/player/{nickname}";
    final Map<String, String> nickname = new HashMap<String, String>();
    nickname.put("nickname", score.getPlayer());
    String Uri = "http://localhost:8081/game/{code}";
    final Map<String, String> code = new HashMap<String, String>();
    code.put("code", score.getGamecode());
    Player player = restTemplate.getForObject(Url, Player.class, nickname);
    Game game = restTemplate.getForObject(Uri, Game.class, code);
```

but I have an error

```
Connection refused
```

in the console
and error:

```
 "I/O error on GET request for \"http://localhost:8080/player/sahar1\": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect"
```

in the Postman

could you help me how can I send GET request with requestParam?
the POST method:

```
    @PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> createScore(@RequestBody @JsonView(Views.class) @Valid  Score score) {
    final String Url = "http://localhost:8080/player?nickname={nickname}";
    final Map<String, String> nickname = new HashMap<String, String>();
    nickname.put("nickname", score.getPlayer());
    String Uri = "http://localhost:8081/game?code={code}";
    final Map<String, String> code = new HashMap<String, String>();
    code.put("code", score.getGamecode());
    Player player = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/player/" + nickname, Player.class);
    Game game = restTemplate.getForObject(Uri, Game.class, code);
    if ((repo.findByScoreid(score.getScoreid())) == null) {
        if((player!= null) && (game!=null)) {
            HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map.put("score", score.getScore());
            map.put("date", score.getDate());
            m = null;
            m.add(map);
            score.setHistory(m);
            repo.save(score);
        return ResponseEntity.status(201).body("Created!");
        }
        else return ResponseEntity.status(400).body("Bad Request!");
    }
    
    else
        return ResponseEntity.status(409).body("Conflict!");
    }
}
```

Comment: check if your app is running on 8080?

Comment: @stacker share your API code

Comment: @stacker yes it is works

Comment: @Rajesh I did it

Comment: Maybe the firewall is blocking it?